# Simulate submission of custom form as a webform

Tags: webforms, forms

I've a custom module that generate a form, it allows user to submit some data to website.
I'm looking for a nice way to display those submit and I would very much like to use [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module for this (because it is already used a lot in company).

I would appreciate any help especially with some snippets.

I found only this post:
[Submit a custom form as a webform submission](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/67971/submit-a-custom-form-as-a-webform-submission)
but that is almost nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to create a Webform submission programmatically:

```
global $user;
$node = node_load(YOUR_NODE_ID);

// Prepare the data. Do note that the keys in this array must match the elements
// in your webform.
$data = array(
  1 => array('Field one value'),
  2 => array('Field two value'),
  3 => array('Field three value'),
);

// Create the submission object.
$submission = new stdClass();
$submission->uid = $user->uid;
$submission->nid = $node->nid;
$submission->submitted = REQUEST_TIME;
$submission->remote_addr = ip_address();
// This is necessary to mark the submission as complete.
$submission->is_draft = FALSE;
$submission->data = $data;

// Store the submission.
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
webform_submission_insert($node, $submission);

// If necessary, invoke the email sending for this Webform.
webform_submission_send_mail($node, $submission);
```

Hope this helps.